# Markov Model for a Traffic Intersection

Tags: ai-design, reinforcement-learning, training, markov-chain

I need some help in developing a Markov Model for a crossroads there is no one way road and i am assuming at this time that traffic is only allowed to go straight no turns are allowed. There are 4 roads and 4 signals(agents).

Comment: What are you trying to observe? Markov models are powerful for making observation from a hidden variable. What are you starting states and what is the injected information?

Comment: I am trying to find a optimal policy for reducing the waiting time of traffic on signal. and about the sates I am confused i do not know how to start and proceed with multiple agents.

Comment: If you draw your intersection maybe we can get a better idea of what you mean.
Is it a requirement to have multiple agents? If you can restrict that the all of the traffic lights are never set in such a way as to cause accidents (all green), it should reduce to a smaller state space and be easier to consider.

Comment: As far i am able to think, you need traffic data for all roads, Based on that you can identify congestion time/traffic using MM/HMM/SSM. Based on traffic at each road at same time, you can optimise the waiting time.

Comment: it is ready now you can try it @ https://github.com/aawadall/SmartTrafficIntersection it is text based though, you can extend it to have a graphical component to it, or if you want you can port it to whatever language you prefer

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a single agent to control the intersection with the following rules:

- define 8 traffic lights
- Each light has two possible values, 0 or 1, with 0 = Red and 1 = Green
- Lights are as follows:

  - 0 = North to South
  - 1 = North to East (Left Turn)
  - 2 = East to West
  - 3 = East to South (Left Turn)
  - 4 = South to North
  - 5 = South to West (Left Turn)
  - 6 = West to East
  - 7 = West to North (Left Turn)
- map lights into a bitmap of 8 bits, with the least significant bit (left bit) is the North to south

Given the above, we have the following valid moves, which are both State Space  and Action Space :

- State/Move 0 - Vertical Moves only   = 10001000
- State/Move 1 - Horizontal Moves only = 00100010
- State/Move 2 - Originated from North only = 11000000
- State/Move 3 - Originated from East only = 00110000
- State/Move 4 - Originated from South only = 00001100
- State/Move 5 - Originated from West only = 00000011
- State/Move 6 - Vertical Diagonal only = 01000100
- State/Move 7 - Horizontal Diagonal only = 00010001

i.e. **S** = {10001000, 10001000, 00100010, 11000000, 00110000, 00001100, 00000011, 01000100, 00010001}

and  **A** = {10001000, 10001000, 00100010, 11000000, 00110000, 00001100, 00000011, 01000100, 00010001}
[image]
Now we have *a* ∈ **A** and *s* ∈ **S** and at any given *s*, *a* will cause the next state *s'* to have the same value of *a*

Final component to complete the moel, is the reward signal, which can be simply the negative sum of time spent per car in the intersection

i.e.     r<sub>t+1</sub> = -∑<sub>c<sub>i</sub> ∈ **Cars**</sub> time(c<sub>i</sub>)

a single agent, will be able to optimize the solution to avoid punishment (negative value caused by wait time)

#### Update

You can increase the state space to double or triple its size to accommodate for time, by appending a time counter component to the bitmap. 
in addition to an extra (9th) action of do nothing,

This should give a more subtle traffic controller. *e.g.* Vertical Traffic Only, at timer = 0 can be represented by 100010000000 or in hex 880, then at time 1 = 881, and so on until time 15 to be 88F.

### Update 2

You can find the source code [here](https://aawadall.github.io/SmartTrafficIntersection/) and [here](https://github.com/aawadall/SmartTrafficIntersection.git)

Comment: By the way, I started implementing this solution in C#, if you are interested, I can send you an invite to its git repository